# Are the Azure SDK Samples for using Sql Data Services still relevant since the ACE model is gone?

Tags: azure, ssds

I've just been doing some research into sql data services, and found out that the current ACE model is being phased out for a newer relational model.  It seemed all the samples in the March 2009 CTP were based on the ACE model (like the StorageClient project).  I'm wondering if these are still relevant- they seem to all be based on the ACE approach, but I'm not sure if it's just a REST interface onto the relation back end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correction... the samples in the Windows Azure SDK don't use SQL Data Services at all.  They're running against Windows Azure table storage (which is not changing models and remains based on ADO.NET Data Services).  So the samples you're looking at are entirely valid.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. The new direction SDS has taken means that the ACE model will be dropped. They will support a REST interface and you can use ADO.Net Data Services to communicate with it.

You've problably read this, but [here's the post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ssds/archive/2009/03/10/9469228.aspx) in which they announced the changes

Comment: Right, but are you using REST to get into the relationship model, or the ACE model?  I know they're working on the Tabular Data Stream (TDS) connection, but I'm not sure if that means REST is dead.